# How to stop flatmates consuming all your bandwidth with downloads?

Tags: windows, internet, download, qos

So, you live in a flat with 3 other people and in a typical weekend internet navigation as much voip is pretty much useless. You do some tracking and finds out all flavours of downloads; torrents, emule, https and etc.

My flatmates are all willing to set up limits and routes on their clients, but telling geeks to respect that when they are locked in their rooms is like asking people to respect QoS over the internet...

We don't have exactly a "router box" (I mean, apart from the ISP router/wifi hub itself) set at home to take care of that, and I'd prefer not to have one, to avoid actual investment. Nevertheless, I'd like to make internet usage minimally fair for those who just want to facebook now and then...

My question is, what are the simplest solutions you guys have found for the situation above? Is there anyway I could get "user immune" without involving configuring a linux box to create shares and quotas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend getting a cheap supported router for DD WRT.  http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index

This is custom firmware for popular routers and has a whole lot of features you might be interested in.  From the admin page you can view bandwidth graphs, check stats and setup QoS if you would like.

Here is the link that goes into detail on this: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quality_of_Service

While this is not the best solution, it is very cheap and probably has the basic feature set you are looking for and maintenance will be low.